# How to declare Closure `function use` in PHP extension?

Tags: php, c

I learning php extension write in C.

How to achieve this in a PHP extension?

```
function($headler) {
    return function ($request) use ($handler) {
        return $handler($request, $options);
    };
}
```

I'm try use the zend_create_closure API below.

```
zval
f;
zend_function
zf;
zf.common.type = ZEND_INTERNAL_FUNCTION;
zf.common.arg_info = (zend_arg_info *)&arginfo_http_errors_1; // request arg info
zf.common.num_args = 1;
zf.common.required_num_args = 1;
zf.common.prototype = NULL;
zf.common.scope = NULL;
zf.internal_function.handler = http_errors_1;
zend_create_closure(&f, &zf, NULL, NULL, NULL);
php_var_dump(&f, 1); // dump PHP class struct

RETURN_ZVAL(&f, 1, 0);
```

How to achieve `use` keyword in a PHP extension??

Comment: maybe with zend_closure_bind_var() ?

Comment: @hwde I'm try use the zend_closure_bind_var func. Symbol not found _zend_closure_bind_var Expected in: flat namespace